# Beginning Haskell - getting Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘(String, String)’

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I have the following, where I am converting a Plain node of an abstract syntax tree for Markdown to a Link node using pandoc:

```
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Walk (walk)

test :: Block -> Block
test (Plain xs) = Link xs "http://www.example.com/" ""
test x = x

readDoc :: String -> Pandoc
readDoc = readMarkdown def

writeDoc :: Pandoc -> String
writeDoc = writeMarkdown def

main :: IO ()
main = interact (writeDoc . walk test . readDoc)
```

The definitions for Link etc. are [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/1.12.4/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L239).

When I compile, I get that on line 5, `Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘(String, String)’` How can I correct my notation? (I am new to Haskell.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Link` has type `[Inline] -> Target -> Inline`, where `Target` is defined as `type Target = (String, String)`. Your second parameter should be a tuple of two strings:

```
test :: Block -> Block
test (Plain xs) = Link xs ("http://www.example.com/", "")
test x = x
```

Comment: Doesn't it have type `[Inline] -> Target -> Inline`? In which case he'll have to do a bit more, too, to get back to a `Block` at the end.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I ended up using `test (Plain xs) = Plain [Link xs ("http://www.example.com/", "")]`.